# How Do I Upload a File To a Folder Online Without Getting "Access to the path is denied"

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, dotnetnuke

I am trying to upload an image file to my web application online. This is how am uploading images file online.

```
if (!FileUploadPropertyImage.HasFile)
{
    Skin.AddModuleMessage(this, Localization.GetString("NoFileFound.ErrorMessage", LocalResourceFile), ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType.RedError);
    return;
}

string PictureFileTypeAccepted = "jpg,png,gif";

if (FileUploadPropertyImage.PostedFile.ContentLength <= maxFileSize * 1024)
{
    string fileName = FileUploadPropertyImage.FileName.ToLower();
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    if (PictureFileTypeAccepted.Contains(extension.ToLower()))
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap objBmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(FileUploadPropertyImage.PostedFile.InputStream, false);

        int imageWidth = objBmp.Width;
        int imageHeight = objBmp.Height;
        int minWidth = 1100;
        int minHeight = 400;

        if (imageWidth <= 2000 && imageHeight <= 800 && (imageWidth > minWidth && imageHeight > minHeight))
        {
            var mapPath = Server.MapPath($"\\Portals\\0\\Images\\WebGeneralPropertiesFolder\\");

            var fileSavePath = new DirectoryInfo(mapPath).FullName;

            hiddenFieldPropertyImageUrl.Value = fileSavePath + "//" + FileUploadPropertyImage.FileName;
            FileUploadPropertyImage.PostedFile.SaveAs(hiddenFieldPropertyImageUrl.Value);

           hiddenFieldPropertImageName.Value =  FileUploadPropertyImage.FileName;

        }
        else
        {
            var wrongFileDimension = Localization.GetString("WrongFileDimension", LocalResourceFile);
            wrongFileDimension = wrongFileDimension.Replace("#Height#", pictureHeight.ToString());
            wrongFileDimension = wrongFileDimension.Replace("#Width#", pictureWidth.ToString());

            Skin.AddModuleMessage(this, wrongFileDimension, ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType.RedError);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Skin.AddModuleMessage(this, Localization.GetString("InvalidFileExtension.ErrorMessage", LocalResourceFile), ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType.RedError);
    }
}
else
{
    Skin.AddModuleMessage(this, Localization.GetString("FileTooBig.ErrorMessage", LocalResourceFile),
        ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType.RedError);
}
```

but instead am getting these error messages.

> (Error: Property is currently unavailable.
>   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Access to the path
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Portals\0\Images\WebGeneralPropertiesFolder\kansas-Image2.jpg'
>   is denied. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Portals\0\Images\WebGeneralPropertiesFolder\kansas-Image2.jpg'
>   is denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare
>   share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
>   secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath,
>   Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
>   FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) at
>   System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) at
>   GeoscomTech.VenueHub.Property.View.UploadPropertyImage() in
>   C:\MyProjects\www.venuehub.local.ng\DesktopModules\Property\View.ascx.cs:line
>   1717 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---)

I am building my application with Dnn Content Management, ASP.Net and C# language.
I am hosting the application on Amazon Web Services. 
Using MSSQL and IIS, in IIS I have given full permission to iis Apppool\DefaultApppool, Network Service, Administrator. Still unable to upload file online.

This is my first time hosting on AWS. Although i have hosted this kind of application on other hosting providers and it was working fine.

The funny thing is that it is working perfectly well on my local server. I would appreciate your feed back, thank you.

Comment: The web server user (windows user) has no access rights to the specified folder. I would just move the images to the location that the web server can access.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the directory in which you are uploading the image exists ?
"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Portals\0\Images\WebGeneralPropertiesFolder"

Best to ensure this before using SaveAs method

```
if (!Directory.Exists(fileSavePath ))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(fileSavePath);
```

Comment: He is getting "access denied" error which clearly indicates no access rights. Non-existent file would cause different error.

Comment: Yes zeeshan, the directory exist. var fileSavePath = new DirectoryInfo(mapPath).FullName;
                                if (!Directory.Exists(fileSavePath))
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(fileSavePath);

Comment: can you try this, delete the existing folder and let it get created through the code, this way I presume that the identity which is running on iis app pool will become the owner and so should have the full authority on that folder.

Comment: I have tried creating the directory where the image should be saved, but still not working online.